# jquery mobile data-collapsed="true" is not working. The list still stays expanded

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

My collapsable list still stay expanded when you navigate to the page. Here is the code for the list.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" >
<h3>Stock #2 Order #2</h3>
 <ul data-role="listview">
 <li>Info 1</li>
 <li>Info 2</li>
 <li>Info 3</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: You mean when you navigate away and return to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand the content when the page loads you have to add the `data-collapsed="false"` attribute to the wrapper.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
```

To collapse the content when the page loads you have to add the `data-collapsed="true"` attribute to the wrapper. This is the default behavior (`data-collapsed="true"`).

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
```

You could use the below ways to expand-collapse the collapsible as well:

```
$('.selector').trigger('expand');

$('.selector').trigger('collapse');
```

I hope this helps.